# AngularJS ng-repeat dynamic rowspan

Tags: angularjs

I have some data array like :

```
arr = [

{"name": "John", "age": 17, "brothers":[{"name":"steve"},{"name":"james"},"name":"robert","name":"juzu"],
{"name": "Doe", "age": 18, "brothers":[{"name":"kelly"},{"name":"smith"}, "name":"herry"],
{"name": "John Doe", "age": 19, "brothers":[{"name":"old"},{"name":"sch"}, {"name":"Jee"},{"name":"hero"},{"name":"tony"}],

];
```

i want to create table like :

[image: LIKE THIS]

but, my td for showing brothers.name limit to 2.
and if my borthers.name data > 2, my arr.name rowspan add +1

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: use `rowspan="{{somevar.brothers.length}}"`

Comment: yes, i have. bu my table not showing nothing.

Comment: can you give me some jsfiddle, YOU?

Comment: @JehanRamadhan why wouldn't you start a fiddle or plunker instead of expecting others to do it for you? This isn't a free coding service. The more effort you put in, the more help you will get

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/c47xK/112/ like this, but in member colom, i want my td is horizontal with ilimit to 2. not vertical.

Comment: I suggest you map the data first into columns then. The logic needed won't be simple using `ng-repeat` alone on a flat array. But if you generate columns arrays then you can use a horizontal ng-repeat also. Or don't use `<table>` and do it with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any modification of your data you could use the Math operations, but try another way to show the data like modals or inner tables for each parent data

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th colspan="2">Brothers</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="display: none"  ng-repeat-start="(k1, v1) in data"></tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="{{ Math.ceil(v1.brothers.length/2) }}">{{v1.name}}</td>
                <td>{{v1.brothers[0].name  }}</td>
                <td>{{v1.brothers[1].name  }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="(k2, v2) in calcData(v1.brothers)">
                <td>{{v1.brothers[v2].name || '' }}</td>
                <td>{{v1.brothers[v2+1].name || ''}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: none" ng-repeat-end></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('App', []);
angular.module('App').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Math = window.Math;
    $scope.data = [{
        "name": "John",
        "age": 17,
        "brothers": [{ "name": "steve" }, { "name": "james" }, { "name": "robert" }, { "name": "juzu" }]
    }, {
        "name": "Doe",
        "age": 18,
        "brothers": [{ "name": "kelly" }, { "name": "smith" }, { "name": "herry" }]
    }, {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 19,
        "brothers": [{ "name": "old" }, { "name": "sch" }, { "name": "Jee" }, { "name": "hero" }, { "name": "tony" }]
    }
    ];
    $scope.calcData = function (data) {
        var tempData = angular.copy(data);
        var temp = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= Math.ceil(tempData.slice(2, data.length).length/2); i++) {
            if (i%2==0) {
                temp.push(i+2)
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
});
```

**Output**

[image]